# [MyTarget]-Swift.h does not have MySwiftClass declaration

Tags: swift, objective-c, core-audio

On macOS CoreAudio plugin development, I try to call Swift func from Objective-C code. But I get error:

> Use of undeclared identifier 'MySwiftClass'

I checked these.

- Add "@objc" on Swift class and public func.
- #import "[MyTarget]-Swift.h" on Objective-C code
- On Xcode "Target Membership" of MySwiftClass.swift, MyTarget is checked.
- Set Swift version to Swift5.
- Set macOS min support to 12.3.
- Run xcodebuild on command line and fixed all error

But "[MyTarget]-Swift.h" under ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[MyProject]-[hash] has no declaration of MySwiftClass

I like to know command to generate [MyTarget]-Swift.h, and find out why MySwiftClass is ignored.

If target is macOS app, I can call Swift func from Objective-C code.

Answer (score 0):

I found Xcode [Target]-Swift.h gen tool does not care about "Target Membership". It only see swift files under MyTarget directory.

Failed case files location

- MyTarget1/MyOBJC1Class.m
- MyTarget1/MySwiftClass.swift
- MyTarget2/MyOBJC2Class.m
- Xcode Target Membership of MySwiftClass.swift ON for MyTargert2

Success case files location

- MyTarget1/MyOBJC1Class.m
- MyTarget1/MySwiftClass.swift
- MyTarget2/MyOBJC2Class.m
- MyTarget2/MySwiftClass.swift (exact copy)